# Is the "access" table removed during upgrade?

Tags: 7, upgrading

When a site is upgraded from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 (or any higher version), do the update hooks remove the access table?

I am developing a module that could import the content of that table, and I need to know if after updating to Drupal 7 that database table is not anymore present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The access rules function has been largely removed from core. From the CHANGELOG:

> Refactored the "access rules" component of user module: The user module now provides a simple interface for blocking single IP addresses. The previous functionality in the user module for restricting certain e-mail addresses and usernames is now available as a contributed module. Further, IP address range blocking is no longer supported and should be implemented at the operating system level.

The upgrade path do not remove the `{access}` table. It migrates the entries it can to the new `{blocked_ips}` table, but otherwise keep the content of the `{access}` table in place. See `system_update_7002()` and `system_update_7003()`.

Parent issue: http://drupal.org/node/228594.
Possible replacement for Drupal 7: http://drupal.org/project/user_restrictions.